# c++ puzzle about return value by reference

Tags: c++, reference

```
set<string> foo {
  set<string> a;
  // operation on a
  return a;
}
```

Is there any performance difference if I do:

```
set<string>& foo {
  set<string> a;
  // ops on a
  return a;
}
```

If so, my understanding is that a will be allocated on stack. After foo() returns,
the memory space will be reclaimed. How can we reference to a memory which is claimed?

Comment: `How can we reference to a memory which is claimed?` You just don't.

Comment: You have spotted the problem correctly.  The second version returns a dangling reference, which is completely useless.  The correct way to have good performance in this situation is for `set` to have a move constructor, and use the first piece of code.  The compiler knows that `a` is disappearing and its content can be "stolen" by the return value -- that's what move construction does.

Answer (score 5):

In case B, any actual use of the returned value results in undefined behavior.  You are not allowed to return a local automatic variable by reference and expect anyone to be able to access it.

See this [live work space](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3jlfYn%243) warning message.  Your compiler will usually warn you when you do something like that, but relying on it is not always advised.

Note that in C++11, the first example is highly efficient.  Betweeen lvalue reference based move and NRVO, the cost to return a local `std::vector<std::string>` by value is on the order of a few ifs and copying a 32 bits of memory, or in some cases less (ie, actually zero cost, because the `std::set` gets constructed in the callers scope directly).

Comment: The first case has basically always been efficient, thanks to return value optimisation, which is explicitly endorsed by the standard.

Comment: @KerrekSB Except RVO in practice only usually works if the body of the first case is visible at the calling site.  Implicit move happens regardless of visibility.

Comment: That doesn't sound plausible. RVO is a purely local property of a function implementation. Only the translation unit implementing that function needs to know whether or not it performs RVO. (It's very easy to confirm this yourself with a little test involving two TUs and only changing `-fno-elide-constructors` on one of them and relinking.)

Comment: @KerrekSB Hmm.  I tried to construct an alternative case, and each attempt failed.  I may have a serious misunderstanding of RVO's limitations...  [This SO link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615231/g-how-rvo-works-in-case-that-multiple-translation-units-are-involved) illuminated my misunderstanding nicely.

Answer (score 1):

There is no point discussing performance of a code which is not correct, like your second snippet, which behaviour is undefined (this will normally make your program crash). You cannot return references to automatic objects (allocated on stack), local to the function.

It would be ok if, for example, your `foo` function was a member function of a class, and was returning a reference to a member of the class:

```
class C {
public:
  set<string>& foo1 { return a_; }
  set<string> foo2 { return a_; }
private:
  set<string> a_;
}
```

In the above example `foo1` wil be more efficient than `foo2` cause it will not create any new object, just return a reference to the existing one.